Geoserver ImageMosaic with Postgres store instantiation
I am trying to set up an ImageMosaic store on a local instance of Geoserver. I set up a postgreSQL DB with Postgis extension for managing the images' info and tried to follow this documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html
However, while I managed to create a workspace, I receive an error in the creation of the store:
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:pacioos_CRW_SST and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@35cc91c5 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3ce334a6[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@7daf48e0 STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true
Here are the properties files that I am using (anyhow they should be ok, as they are successfully employed in another project):
datastore.properties
host=localhost
port=17001
database=postgis
schema=pacioos
user=**************
passwd=*************
Loose\ bbox=true
Estimated\ extends=false
validate\ connections=true
Connection\ timeout=10
preparedStatements=true 

indexer.properties
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)

timeregex.properties
regex=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}
Finally, my image is a GeoTIFF having name "CRW_SST_Milano_20240501T120000.tif"
Geoserver's version is 2.23.0
Can anyone help me?

You need to check the log file to find out what really went wrong
